# In C#, what and how to pass IServiceProvider in ErrorListProvider(IServiceProvider isp)?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, vsix, service-provider, error-list

I am creating a vsix project where I need to add some custom errors in Error List window. Now I am stuck in `IServiceProvider`. What it contains and why I need this and how I can get this? In my code, I need to initialize with a service provider. How can I do this? Following is code :

```
internal class ErrorListManager
{
    public static ErrorListProvider errorListProvider;

    public static void Initialize(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) 
    {
        errorListProvider = new ErrorListProvider(serviceProvider);

    }

    public static void AddError(string errorMsg) {
        AddTask(errorMsg, TaskErrorCategory.Error);
    }

    private static void AddTask(string errorMsg, TaskErrorCategory category)
    {
        errorListProvider.Tasks.Add(new ErrorTask
        {
            Category = TaskCategory.User,
            ErrorCategory = category,
            Text = errorMsg
        });
    }
}
```

Please help. I am a beginner for C# and VSIX. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write something in **VS Error List** you need to use **ErrorListProvider**. In my implementation, I inherit from **ErrorListProvider** and implement my own behavior for "ErrorWindowController". The code looks like this (read the code comments for more information):

```
public class ErrorWindowController : ErrorListProvider
{

#region Constructor

/// <summary>
/// Instance Constructor
/// </summary>
/// <param name="aServiceProvider"></param>
public ErrorWindowController(IServiceProvider aIServiceProvider) : base(aIServiceProvider)
{
}

#endregion


#region Public Methods

// Use this to add a collection of custom errors in VS Error List
public void AddErrors(IEnumerable<ErrorModel> aErrors)
{
    SuspendRefresh();

    foreach (ErrorModel error in aErrors)
    {
      ErrorTask errorTask = new ErrorTask
      {
        ErrorCategory = error.Category,
        Document = error.FilePath,
        Text = error.Description,
        Line = error.Line - 1,
        Column = error.Column,
        Category = TaskCategory.BuildCompile,
        Priority = TaskPriority.High,
        HierarchyItem = error.HierarchyItem
      };
      errorTask.Navigate += ErrorTaskNavigate;
      Tasks.Add(errorTask);
    }

    BringToFront();
    ResumeRefresh();
}

// Remove all the errors from Error List which are depending of a project and this specific project is closed
// Or remove all the errors from Error List when the VS solution is closed
public void RemoveErrors(IVsHierarchy aHierarchy)
{
    SuspendRefresh();

    for (int i = Tasks.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
      var errorTask = Tasks[i] as ErrorTask;
      aHierarchy.GetCanonicalName(Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSConstants.VSITEMID_ROOT, out string nameInHierarchy);
      errorTask.HierarchyItem.GetCanonicalName(Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSConstants.VSITEMID_ROOT, out string nameErrorTaskHierarchy);
      if (nameInHierarchy == nameErrorTaskHierarchy)
      {
        errorTask.Navigate -= ErrorTaskNavigate;
        Tasks.Remove(errorTask);
      }
    }

    ResumeRefresh();
}

// Remove all the errors from the Error List
public void Clear()
{
    Tasks.Clear();
}


#endregion


#region Private Methods

// This is optional
// Add navigation for your errors. 
private void ErrorTaskNavigate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ErrorTask objErrorTask = (ErrorTask)sender;
  objErrorTask.Line += 1;
  bool bResult = Navigate(objErrorTask, new Guid(EnvDTE.Constants.vsViewKindCode));
  objErrorTask.Line -= 1;
}


#endregion
}
```

The **ErrorModel** is very simple:

```
public class ErrorModel
{
  #region Properties

  public string FilePath { get; set; }

  public int Line { get; set; }

  public int Column { get; set; }

  public TaskErrorCategory Category { get; set; }

  public string Description { get; set; }

  public IVsHierarchy HierarchyItem { get; set; }

  #endregion

}
```

Happy Codding!

Comment: May I know what and how you are passing `IServiceProvider aIServiceProvider` when that constructor is called? I created my VSIX project with Menu Command template. Here I've added many other items e.g. Windows Form, TextAdornment. So now, whenever I click on my menu button, then only I get service provider with all necessary things. But when I try to initialize from anywhere else, I dont get service provider.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. The best way I found to manage VS services was to cached all the services I need when the package is asynchronous loading. In this way, the service is always available when you need it, and it's just a one-time operation. In the example above I sent the `IServiceProvider` interface as a parameter because I need just the interface for the base object, `ErrorListProvider`.

Comment: Package asynchronous loading is invoked only when I click on a menu command. But I want this to be loaded when Editor TextView is created. Can I add new asynchronous package from where I can initialize my ErrorListManager Initialize method?

Comment: I forgot to mention before, I'm using the following attribute to force the VSIX package loading when Visual Studio is started: `[ProvideAutoLoad(VSConstants.UICONTEXT.NoSolution_string, PackageAutoLoadFlags.BackgroundLoad)]`. Let me know if it's working for you

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sir! Now I can do what I actually wanted. One thing with this is, It is taking long time (20-30 seconds) to be initialized.

Comment: I'm glad to help. About the initialization time if you are doing heavy stuff maybe it should be better to take into consideration a lazy initialization of your components or operations. The components that are not really necessary, when the Visual Studio is opened, can be initialized later when a Visual Studio Solution is opened or on another VS event taking into consideration your needs. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! And do you have any idea about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59532595/show-custom-message-in-error-list-c-sharp-vsix-extension) issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your package is a service provider. Its base class AsyncPackage derives from the Package class which implements OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider and System.IServiceProvider (yes, VSX is confusing and there are two IServiceProvider interfaces). So, from your package class you would call ErrorListManager.Initialize(this).

That said, you may want to use the new API of VS 2015 and higher for the ErrorList. The old approach that you are using doesn't allow you to add values to columns such as "Code", etc. See samples here:

VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/ErrorList: https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/ErrorList

madskristensen/WebAccessibilityChecker: https://github.com/madskristensen/WebAccessibilityChecker/tree/master/src/ErrorList

madskristensen/TaskOutputListener: https://github.com/madskristensen/TaskOutputListener/blob/master/src/ErrorListProvider/ErrorListProvider.cs

Comment: What **package class** actually is? Is it the class from where my whole project getting started? Or something else?

Comment: @TanmayBairagi The class where your whole VSIX project is started. It derives from Package or AsyncPackage and it has an Initialize or InitializeAsync override method

Comment: Okey. I created my VSIX project with Menu Command template. Here I've added many other items e.g. Windows Form, TextAdornment. So now, whenever I click on my menu button, then only I get everything I need, Initialize method is properly working. But when I try to initialize from anywhere else, I dont get service provider. Thanks for understending my problem Sir! Is there any solution where I dont need to click on my menu button to get my ErrorListManager class initialized?

Comment: @TanmayBairagi Well, if your ErrorListManager has an Initialize method, something in your code must call that method. Whoever is calling it must pass the IServiceProvider as parameter. What other entry points (" from anywhere else"?) do you have apart from the package with its InitializeAsync method?

Comment: Actually ("from anywhere else") is not an entry point (Package class). And I do not have any `InitializeAsync` method other than the package class. Although I tried to add an **Async Package**  from **("project"->Add->New Item->Extensibility->Async Package)** which automatically creates `InitializeAsync` . But the problem was, I could not load this package anyway. hope you are getting the problem.